# Setup GC log rotate policy for kafka broker servers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, garbage-collection

We have a three node Kafka cluster and I just found that the GC log has been set up without setting up the log rotate policy.

Now the GC log size has reached to 4 GB and we need to move this file and also set up a log rotate policy.

Can this be achieved without restarting the Kafka service?

Answer (score 0):

The GC logs are managed by the JVM. The most common JVMs don't allow changing GC configurations at runtime.

That said, as Kafka (correctly configured) can cope with brokers doing a rolling restart, you can update your GC settings and roll your Kafka cluster. Upon restarting each JVM will pick the new GC logs settings.

Also note that by default Kafka sets a GC logs rotation of 10 files of 100MB max, see https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L272-L292.
So it looks like you've made changes .

Comment: As checked the specified code of line to set log rotate has not been set up in out run-class file. So I will have to add it and restart the kafka service on all the broker servers, right?

Comment: Here is how the gc log is set up in my run-class.sh file.

Comment: # GC options
GC_FILE_SUFFIX='-gc.log'
GC_LOG_FILE_NAME=''
if [ "x$GC_LOG_ENABLED" = "xtrue" ]; then
  GC_LOG_FILE_NAME=$DAEMON_NAME$GC_FILE_SUFFIX
  KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xloggc:$LOG_DIR/$GC_LOG_FILE_NAME -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps "
fi

Comment: I was able to set up the GC policy, however when i started the kafka service after applying the policy the broker went out of sync (ISR). I restarted the kafka and zookeeper service the broker came back in sync however the kafka log size doubled